# Unable to edit post in iOS app: a server with the specific hostname cannot be found

Tags: bug, edits, ios-app, server

[image]

- App Version: 1.6.6.2
- Device: iPad 2 (GSM)
- OS Version: Version 9.3.5 (Build 13G36)

Comment: Is this permanent? How many times you tried? Maybe there was temporary glitch on their server. The site also sometimes fails to submit posts/edits with "Error occured", it happens.

Comment: It works now, thanks. I was unable to reload the question either.

Comment: Well, no site has 100% uptime, SE/SO are not different. Maybe keep an eye, if it happens again edit this report, but otherwise I don't think there is any real problem here.

Comment: @ShadowWizard thanks for the info. When you say no site has 100% uptime, does it count Google too?

Comment: Ugh, it happens again. I write this comment in the Android app

Comment: As for Google, [99.9533% uptime last year](http://montools.com/stats/www.google.com), which is not 100%. :-)

Comment: @ShadowWizard hmm, it's weird that i have the same error when visiting the link in Firefox, while googling random stuff still works, even when the SE app works again